# Cannot retrieve event object from facebook?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can anyone help me, im trying to get this information from facebook:

https://graph.facebook.com/139373546157232/

This is my ajax call, but im getting a 200 bad request in the chrome error console and the following error:

**XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://graph.facebook.com/139373546157232/. Origin http://delete-cardiff.co.uk is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.**

```
 $.ajax({
url : "https://graph.facebook.com/139373546157232/",
success : function(data) {
    //Checking what's returned  
    console.log(data);
},
 dataType : "json"
 });
```

My understanding was I didn't need authentication to get this information? How would I go about retrieving the object?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't retrieve JSON from an external URL.  You need to use [JSONP](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#jsonp).  In jquery, if you include callback=? at the end of your URL then it will work.  Try:

```
$.ajax({
url : "https://graph.facebook.com/139373546157232/?callback=?",
success : function(data) {
   //Checking what's returned  
   console.log(data);
},
dataType : "json"
});
```

Comment: I always forget to add the callback param.. Thank you for that :D

Comment: This is the site I've built to accomodate the feeds, http://delete-cardiff.co.uk/new_site/ Do you know how I would go about adding the correct formatting to the description? so that it's not all in one block?

Comment: You can do a regex replace on "\n" for "<br>"  Something along the lines of `data.description.replace(/\n/, "<br>");`

Comment: I think I used that.. will double check my code to see why it's not working.. Thank you :D